# Conversion of String having date format with AM/PM to DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS format

Tags: oracle

Might be simple but I am unable to resolve this.

I want to do a minus the date between 2 tables for validation- 
One is an external table.
The external table has varchar2 for date column -format is 3/03/2014 6:00:28 AM
 table2 has a date datatype which is of format '03-MAR-2014 06:00:28'.

Can someone help me with this. I am getting errors like ORA29913, ORA 01830 etc while doing minus between 2 after doing a to_date of first string

Thanks,

Comment: what sql have you written?

Comment: Please update your question with your SQL. No need to post it as a comment.

Comment: If SEO_EVENTDATE is date from first table, you should use meridian AM or PM in to_date function(check answer below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for first date convert it like this

```
select to_date('3/03/2014 6:00:28 AM','DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')  from dual
```

and then you can subtract date from table2 directly from this date without need for any conversion.

Comment: hERE is the query   
SELECT
TO_DATE(SEO_EVENTDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS PM')
FROM EXT_EMAIL_OPENS
MINUS
SELECT
SEO_EVENTDATE
FROM EMAIL_OPENS_280314 WHERE PDATE ='12-MAR-2014'


Now I am getting the error ORA01818 HH24 precludes use of meridian indicator

Comment: don't use HH24. use either meridian or 24 time. check date format in answer (its DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM)

Comment: tHANKS A lot crazycloud for turning up so fast. It worked out for me. :)